# Divergence Theorem to determine the flux

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Please how can I determine the flux of the vector field 
$$F=(x+x^2 y){\bf e_x}+ (x y^2-y) {\bf e_y}$$
through the boundary which is formed by the the hyperbola $x^2 -81y^2=9$ and the lines $y=-2$ and $y=1$

I did the div of the vector field , and it is $$4xy$$

but now what to do , what is dv ? and also by which formulas should I represent the x and y?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer below? if so, did you find it useful?

Answer (score 1):

Your $dV$ is really an area element; you are integrating the 2D divergence over the area within the given bounds.

The net flux over this area is given by

$$4 \int_{-2}^1 dy \: y \: \int _{-3 \sqrt{1+9 y^2}}^{3 \sqrt{1+9 y^2}} dx \: x$$

which is zero by symmetry.